# Journey Builder, fails in 2nd attempt

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a filtered data extension; which updates every day with new records and update method is Overwrite. Using that DE I created a journey for the user. Below is Audience setting.

```
NAME
REM-0020
ENTRY AUDIENCE
DAY_01_REMARKETING_TEST_DE
EVALUATE NEW RECORDS ONLY
false
SCHEDULE
December 13, 2016 2:42 PM
TIME ZONE
Eastern Standard Time
REPEAT
Hourly
REPEAT EVERY
1
END DATE
12/13/2066
END AFTER
438290
```

First time when it run, it run successfully and then I manually change the data in DE. But after an hour when journey starts again it fails. And give me error that contact Rejected.

Any solution?

Comment: What have you set the Contact Entry Mode to? (Click on the cog icon to check)

Comment: Contact Entry mode is "Re-entry anytime"

Comment: Any thoughts, @EliotHarper?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just changing the data values, or changing the filter criteria to point to new records?  If it's attempting to evaluate the same record again, even with updated data, it will likely consider it an already-injected subscriber.  Try to create a new record with the data you want to test and see if it helps.

Comment: I was just changing filter criteria, to point to a new record. When you saying "new" I assume it means record is already exists in Master data extension.

Comment: Any thoughts, @Micheal?

Comment: You may try using a SQL-based solution for filter criteria, as I'm not sure how well Filtered DEs can be used for injection.  Just with knowing how it evaluates records internally, the more "native" approach might be best.